# cereal compiles and runs, but does not write to file

Tags: c++, cereal

The following code does not write to file.

```
#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };
    stringstream s;
    s << "cereal_test.xml";
    cereal::XMLOutputArchive  oarchive(s);
    oarchive(v); 
}
```

It compiles and runs apparently correctly.

If we `cout << s << endl;` out of scope we see in the console:

```xml
cereal_test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cereal>
        <value0 size="dynamic">
                <value0>1</value0>
                <value1>2</value1>
                <value2>3</value2>
        </value0>
</cereal>
```

What's missing?

Comment: You say that the code doesn't write to a file, but it doesn't actually *write to a file*. All it does is the serialization to a string stream, nowhere do you write the serialized data to a file.

Comment: That is a fair point. However, this is pretty much copy paste from cereal's documentation https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html ; when we produce a working code I'll pull request that change to their documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mistaken copy-paste from cereal's tuturial:

It should be `ofstream` instead of `stringstream`

```
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };

    std::ofstream outFile("cereal_test.xml");
    {
        cereal::XMLOutputArchive  oarchive(outFile);
        oarchive(v);
    }
}
```